Excel file (extension name: xls) with weird characters
I got a Excel file (the extension name is xls, NOT xlsx) as an Email attachment from my Hungarian colleague, and my computer's OS is Simplified Chinese.
When I opened the Excel, some characters were weird (as the picture below), does anyone can help me resolve this problem? Thanks very much!

I think the red texts in the picture are correct.
I hope the character in Hungarian can be displayed as it should be.

There is no picture in your question. I've upvoted your question, now you should have enough reputation to edit your question and add the picture.

You are referring to an old Excel format, when Unicode and encoding where not a main issues (and not corrected). Can I assume your .xls file is generated (and not created by Excel)? In such case, much metadata are missing (and yes, also Microsoft Access writing Excel miss such things, so it is not just third party, or developers outside Office team)

Is it a real xls or a CSV with a fake extension? A lot of web apps fake Excel exports by returning a CSV or HTML file with a fake extension, expecting Excel to read and import the text data. You can't fix a bad file after the fact. The Excel format since 2007 is xlsx, a ZIP package containing XML documents and has no problems with Unicode. There's absolutely no reason to use xls any more - certainly not compatibility

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks! I think it is a real xls file, when I trying to use notepad open it, it is NOT plain text.

@GiacomoCatenazzi I'll ask the colleague give me a xlsx  and then try it again. Thank you!

Please do not use (sole) images of code/data/errors in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. Post both expected and malformed strings.

You face a mojibake case (example in Python for its universal intelligibility): 'Korlátolt Felelősségű Társaság'.encode( 'cp1250').decode( 'gbk', 'replace') returns 'Korl醫olt Felel鮯s間� T醨sas醙'. There should be an Import function under the File menu in Excel allowing choice of input file encoding. Choose CP1250 (or Central and Eastern Europe).

Agree with JosefZ. In the upper right there's a date with the Hungarian month name that should be "május", but the two characters "áj" are being misinterpreted as the Chinese character "醞". The cp1250 byte sequence for "áj" is 0xE1 0x6A, and that happens to be the byte sequence in the Simplified Chinese code page 936 for "醞". It appears the xls file is using cp1250 encoding but doesn't have that explicitly indicated, and your system is by default assuming the Simplified Chinese code page of your OS system locale setting.

When dealing with file transfers with another language, https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/pbCharsetRef.html provided a characterset transformation tool.

@GiacomoCatenazzi, .xls is Excel97  a really old version, I don't believe it's supported any more.

@Jan: some python modules supported only xls long before the new modules for xlsx were available, and as we see from screeshot, I assume it is a report program which may very old (my experience on "never update working scripts"). In any case the file has dates of 2024, so ... someone is actively using such peleolitic format.
